# Which app store?

Tags: android, codenameone

There's a problem with the codename1 widget for visiting the app
store to leave reviews.  What about apps loaded from app stores
other than google play?

Elsewhere, using PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager()
is recommended, but this is not part of the codename1 api.

Answer (score 0):

No. The widget supports iOS just fine and would work with Windows too provided we give it the right URL's, you can check out the kitchen sink source: https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink

The package manager approach can work on Android but not on iOS so there is no point in porting it just for this. If you want a google play URL you can just get the package from `Display` and construct a URL dynamically.

Comment: Not looking for a URL, just a way to tell which store the app was downloaded from, without resorting to the obvious but inconvenient strategy of uploading a slightly different app.

Comment: That's there in the demo too. We check the OS.

Comment: The demo differentiates between itunes and google play, but not between google play and amazon store.

Comment: You can use a native interface to add that distinction

Answer (score -1):

No, the widget supports fine for both iOS & Windows. I've used the same method in [Tutu Helper Vip](https://appspopo.com/tutuapp/) app store. It works fine for me.